# Time Complexity Analysis: "Cost of a Recursive Call"

Tags: computational-complexity, recursion

When were are talking Time Complexity then as I have understood it. then to perform a while loop that will result in the cost of `n(-1)/2`
Further more the cost of a for loop is `n(n+1)/2 - 1` but what is the cost of a recursive call?

Comment: The time complexity of recursive calls is measured the same way as iterative procedures. However the space of a recursive call is different because each "frame" in the "call stack" will take up some memory.

Comment: @Carpetfizz yes except when you are using [terminale recursion ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Comment: @Nulle I think you didn't understand your course. For estimating the complexity you have to count how many "unit instruction" are needed for executing the algorithm. That there is a `for` or `while` loop or a recursion in your algorithm doesn't change that you have to count how many unit instructions are executed...